# Conditional ReadOnly/Editable Attribute based on Different Roles in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are developing a workflow-like application. We want to display the same form (with the same `ViewModel` and the same `View`) for different user roles. We want to make some fields ReadOnly Not Editable based on specific user roles.

The `ViewModel` would be like:

```
public class ServiceViewModel
{
    [EditableIfInRoles("Administrator", "Editor")]
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

We are planing to create a custom `ReadOnlyAttribute`, like:

```
public class EditableIfInRolesAttribute : EditableAttribute
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _allowedRoles; 

    public EditableIfInRolesAttribute(params string[] allowedRoles) : base(true)
    {
        _allowedRoles = allowedRoles;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Currently we don't know which method to override
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool IsEditable(object value)
    {
        return _allowedRoles.Any(e => HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(e));
    }
}
```

The rendered HTML that we expect for unauthorized user roles is:

```html
<input class="form-control global" id="ServiceID" name="ServiceID" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

How to create a custom attribute that inherits either `ReadOnlyAttribute` or 'EditableAttribute', since both of them are sealed class?

What method to override? Or is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your misunderstanding the usage of `EditableAttribute` It has no affect on the html generated by html helpers. All it does is set the `IsReadOnly` property of the `ModelMetaData`. You could of course read the value using something like

```
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName == "SomeProperty").First().IsReadOnly)
{
  // add the readonly="readonly" attribute to the control
```

but this is not the intended usage.

Some options include

1. Setting a view model or `ViewBag` property (say `bool isReadOnly`)
   and then adding the html `readonly` attribute based on on the value. An example of this approach is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392183/condition-of-html-helper-not-working/27392268#27392268)
2. Create your own html helpers that accept a view model or `ViewBag`
   property. An example of this approach is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482305/access-model-class-instance-from-a-custom-additionalmetadataattribute-asp-net-m/26483022#26483022)
3. If you want to use DataAnnotations, create you own attribute that
   inherits `Attribute` and implements `IMetadataAware` and then create
   your own html helpers that read the attributes properties and add
   the html attributes. An example of this approach is shown in [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519493/customattribute-reflects-html-attribute-mvc5/26519946#26519946)